# How to update values in background in flask?

Tags: multithreading, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm creating flask web site that uses some API to retrieve data.
this API has basic authentication with tokens and each token is valid for X hours.

I'll probably will run this app behind nginx+uwsgi and the configuration will be something like that:

```
[uwsgi]
# Some other config....
master          = true
processes       = 2
enable-threads  = true
threads         = 4
```

So i'm trying to figure out what the best way to maintain updated Auth Token for my processes and their threads.
a common solution is to use a separate script that updates some memcache or some consul solutions and retrieve the data from there but is seems like a overkill for this specific task...

There is some nice way in flask to run some background thread that updates this token? 
(just to be clear its ok if the same server will have couple of auth tokens, like one for each process running....)

Answer (score 0):

Save the token to a db along with the creation time, every now and then check how long it's been and then ask for a new API token if the time has expired. If you are using multiple tokens then specify which token in the db is for what.

If you don't want to use a db then you could write the token and timestamp to a file instead.